# How to access value of for each loop in slide the function

Tags: php, function

My problem is I want to access in the function execute result in for each loop using function calling? How can I do it ?

```
function Getshift($connect,$shiftid)
 {
         $query = "SELECT * FROM `shift` WHERE `shift_Id` = $shiftid ";
         $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
      if($statement->execute())
      {
           $result = $statement->fetchAll();
           foreach($result as $row)
       {
          $shift_Id_tbl = $row['shift_Id'];
          $shift_start_time = date_format( date_create($row['start_time']), 'H:i:s' );
          $shift_start_time_new  = date("H:i:s", strtotime('+15 minutes', strtotime($shift_start_time)));
          $shift_start_time_new02 = date("H:i:s", strtotime('+15 minutes', strtotime($shift_start_time_new)));
          $shift_end_time = date_format( date_create($row['end_time']), 'H:i:s' );
          $earliest_arrival_time = date_format( date_create($row['earliest_arrival_time']), 'H:i:s' );
          $lastest_arrival_time = date_format( date_create($row['lastest_arrival_time']), 'H:i:s' );
          $minimum_time_gap = date_format( date_create($row['minimum_time_gap']), 'H:i:s' );

        }
      }  
 }
```

I want to access the `$shift_start_time` value using function calling ?
I try something like that

```
Getshift($connect,$shiftid);
```

Comment: you mean if you call Getshift function you want to get the $shift_start_time value?

Comment: yes somthing like that

Comment: what does your $result returning?

Comment: i want to access the for each loop value in my calculation.

Comment: Do you want to get all values for `$shift_start_time` in an array like format when using the function call e.g array([0] => '28.10.2019', [1] => '27.10.2019' or only a specific value to be returned, e.g. '28.10.2019'

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return all $shift_start_time values when you call the function you need to store those values and return them at the end of the function.

Something like this:

```
function Getshift($connect,$shiftid)
 {
         $query = "SELECT * FROM `shift` WHERE `shift_Id` = $shiftid ";
         $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
         $shift_start_times = array();
      if($statement->execute())
      {
           $result = $statement->fetchAll();
           foreach($result as $row)
       {
          $shift_Id_tbl = $row['shift_Id'];
          $shift_start_time = date_format( date_create($row['start_time']), 'H:i:s' );
          $shift_start_times[] = $shift_start_time;
          $shift_start_time_new  = date("H:i:s", strtotime('+15 minutes', strtotime($shift_start_time)));
          $shift_start_time_new02 = date("H:i:s", strtotime('+15 minutes', strtotime($shift_start_time_new)));
          $shift_end_time = date_format( date_create($row['end_time']), 'H:i:s' );
          $earliest_arrival_time = date_format( date_create($row['earliest_arrival_time']), 'H:i:s' );
          $lastest_arrival_time = date_format( date_create($row['lastest_arrival_time']), 'H:i:s' );
          $minimum_time_gap = date_format( date_create($row['minimum_time_gap']), 'H:i:s' );

        }
      }
      return $shift_start_times;
 }
```

When you call your function you can just loop over those values to show them:

```
$shift_start_times = Getshift($connect,$shiftid); 
foreach($shift_start_times as $shift_start_time) {
    echo $shift_start_time;
}
```